# Validation for Dynamic check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did one dynamic validation for check box.
All check box name and id are dynamic
Whether check box is checked or not.
This my coding.but i did't get it.

```
if($("input[class='chkclass']:checked").length < 0){
                alert('Answer Should be Mandatory');
                submitAllow = false;
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: What if the checkbox has more than one class? You should use `$(".chkclass:checked")`. Also `.length` will never return anything `< 0` afaik

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ($('.chkclass').prop('checked')) {
            alert('Answer Should be Mandatory');
            submitAllow = false;
            return false;
 }
```

See if that would work? Or even better rather assign the checkbox a unique ID and use it like such:

```
     if ($('#idhere').prop('checked')) {
            alert('Answer Should be Mandatory');
            submitAllow = false;
            return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do I think

```
if($("input.chkclass:checked").length){
```